# What is the use of cURL in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

In PHP, I see the word cURL in many PHP projects. What is it? How does it work?
Link http://php.net/curl

Comment: You copied this question thinking you will get upvotes just like the question you copied from

Comment: Click on “Introduction” on the page you linked to, and _read_ …?

Answer (score 0):

Curl is a command line tool for doing all sorts of URL manipulations and transfers, but this particular document will focus on how to use it when doing HTTP requests for fun and profit. I'll assume that you know how to invoke 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' to get basic information about it.

Curl is not written to do everything for you. It makes the requests, it gets the data, it sends data and it retrieves the information. You probably need to glue everything together using some kind of script language or repeated manual invokes.

Taken from: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

Answer (score 0):

we usually use it get the Return value of a  Interface like this:

```
        $oCurl = curl_init();
    if(stripos($url,"https://")!==FALSE){
        curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1); //CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1
    }
    curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    $sContent = curl_exec($oCurl);
    $aStatus = curl_getinfo($oCurl);
    curl_close($oCurl);
    if(intval($aStatus["http_code"])==200){
        return $sContent;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```